# How to use :nth-child correctly to target individual elements?

Tags: html, css, sass

So I have a `<ul>` with five `<li>` tags nested with in. I want to style them all differently and have been experimenting with `:nth-child` to try and target each `<li>` element instead of adding any classes etc.

My `.scss` file looks like this:

```
  ul {
    display: inline-block;
    li:nth-child(1) {
      list-style-type: none;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      background: blue;
    }
    li:nth-child(2) {
      list-style-type: none;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      background: red;
    }
    li:nth-child(3) {
      list-style-type: none;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      background: white;
    }
    li:nth-child(4) {
      list-style-type: none;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      background: pink;
    }
  }
```

*I've only added in colours to try and notice my style changes pick up easier*

However, i'm not targeting each `<li>` element and changing the colour but only a few and only getting the colour blue to show. What have I misunderstood? Any help?

Comment: What does "but only a few" mean? What's the problem? Rather than SCSS, show rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: Please explain what is not working.

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://liveweave.com/qQZeK4

Comment: That's very repetitive for SCSS though. You might want to look into that.

Comment: @Paulie_D What would be a better solution for `.scss`? I thought that it looked quite repetitive myself but wasn't sure of a good workaround.

Comment: Style the base list item then only add the styles that apply individually to each separate list item. I'm on a mobile device right now so I can't demo. However that's secondary to your issue.

Comment: Fixed the issue.

Thanks for the feedback, i'll defiantly do what you suggested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is working, however, yuo first should try to target your selectors differently, for example:

```
ul{
  li{
    &:nth-child(2){
      /* Your code here */
    }
  }
}
```

Also, note the :first-child and :last-child pseudo-selectors exist.

In the end, what I would advice you to do is, if possible, add the color or background color programatically as it seems to be more content-specific than a theme constraint. And, if you cannot use your server to do that, maybe try to look into sass lists and @for directives. It could help you have a maintanable code.

Comment: How is this any different than what the OP already has?  The code compiles to the same thing.

Comment: It is just a cleaner solution. But this is indeed exactly the same css output.